# All PDFs default as a picture of ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

Cinnamon Mint. All PDFs suddenly now open in default to a ghastly image of an 'ImageMagick' clown. i tried every one of your recommendations : Setting 'Document Viewer' as 'default' don't work, resetting system defaults don't work. i uninstaled 'ImageMagick' in terminal but, unless i right-click and elect Document Viewer for EVERY PDF it still defaults to an image of that horrible clown !